# Geolocation Mobile Testing for web geolocation without https

Tags: javascript, iphone, geolocation

I have some geolocation code on a web page and all it does is to show a pointer on my geolocation.
For testing is works fine on my local computer when I just open the .html file on my web browser.
The problem is that I need to test it when moving so I want to open it on my mobile.

I have tried enabling location services on my mobile but still no marker.
The problem is that this is not a cordova or mobile app, just a web page and I don't have host with https so my question is...

How do I get the geolocation on my web page to work on my mobile for testing purposes? Are there any browsers or settings (iphone) that will stop this geolocation restrictions so I can test my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [USB debugging](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/) then [as long as you don't need your server] you can unplug your mobile and wander around.